# JSTL Split method not working properly?

Tags: split, jstl, jstl-functions

I'm trying to split a string using JSTL method and splitting it on the basis of four quotes `''''`. Below are the details:

```
example = ''''THE FAMOUS DIAMONDS''''This is second string for the example''''/content/dam/rcq/mp_push_tank_style.jpg''''right''''
${fn:split(example,\"''''\")}
example[0]=THE FAMOUS DIAMONDS
example[1]=This is second string for the example
example[2]=/content/dam/abc/tank.jpg
example[3]=right
```

For Above mentioned string it's working fine but issue is whenever their is a `'(single quote)` in my string and it's functionality get break. Below is example

```
example = ''''THE FAMOUS DIAMONDS''''This is  string's contains single quote''''/content/dam/rcq/mp_push_tank_style.jpg''''right''''
${fn:split(example,\"''''\")}
example[0]=THE FAMOUS DIAMONDS
example[1]=This is  string
example[2]=s contains single quote
example[3]=/content/dam/abc/tank.jpg
```

Now as you see example[2] contains text instead of imagepath.

Can anybody help in this, as i can't change the split type `''''`.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue in `jstl-function fn:split()` for using *`apostrophe`* instead of that you can use `scriptlet` in which split will work perfectly. Here I have done for you:

```
<c:set var="string1" value="''''THE FAMOUS DIAMONDS''''This is  string's contains single quote''''/content/dam/rcq/mp_push_tank_style.jpg''''right''''"/>
<%
    String s=(String)pageContext.getAttribute("string1");
    String[] string = s.split("''''");
    pageContext.setAttribute("string",string);
 %>
<c:set var="string2" value="${string}"/>
<p>String(0) : ${string2[0]}</p>
<p>String(1) : ${string2[1]}</p>
<p>String(2) : ${string2[2]}</p>
<p>String(3) : ${string2[3]}</p>
<p>String(4) : ${string2[4]}</p>
```

Output:

```
String(0) :
String(1) : THE FAMOUS DIAMONDS
String(2) : This is string's contains single quote
String(3) : /content/dam/rcq/mp_push_tank_style.jpg
String(4) : right
```